# gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: gradle, installation

I install gradle and set PATH variable.
When I change folder in cmd on right and wrote
`gradle -v`
I got from cmd the request:

- 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file. *
  How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution the problem.
In my case solution is uninstall antivirus and reinstall program and again install antivirus. (I using Comodo antivirus)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and how the antivirus program solves your issue?